# Calling PHP variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to call a variable (id) from PHP in a HTML/ Javascript where the ID of the row from the DB will be sent to another page, from the anchor, so that rows details can be viewed in a table.

```
var eventContent = $('<div class="event-info">' + '<h4 class="event-name">' + point.name + '</h4><hr>' +
        '<span><h5>Date: </h5>' +
        '<p class="event-date">' + point.edate + '</p></span>' +
        '<p class="event-description">'+ point.description +'</p>' + 
        '<input type="button" id="view-event"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="showDetails();" value="View Event" />'+
        '<a href="details.php<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove Event</a>' +
        '</div>');
```

So for example, there a number of different events saved and displayed, and when the VIEW button is clicked - it opens a new page where the event with that ID is shown in a table.

**UPDATE:**
I also tried it by creating the details list in the PHP/HTML:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<div class='event-details' id='event-details' style='display: none'>";
                    echo "<h3>Event Details</h3>";
                    echo "<table class='table'>";
                    echo "<tr><th>Event Name: </th><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><th>Event Date: </th><td>" . $row['edate'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><th>Event Type: </th><td>" . $row['category'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><th>Event Details: </th><td>" . $row['description'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo"</table>";
                    echo "<td><a href='details.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>View</a></td></div>";
                }
```

It then displays in javascript, using clone():

```
var eventList = $("#event-details").clone().show();

google.maps.event.addListener(event_markers[i], "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(eventList[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, event_markers[i]);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
```

Now this way sends the ID to input, BUT it sends the same ID to each item - There are currently 5 rows in the DB with id's from 6 to 10, but when the page loads, it sends the first ID (6) to all of the events, rather than giving each one its own unique ID from the DB.

Comment: PHP is server side code, so as the server processes a request to access a file, the code is compiled and parsed into HTML. JS is client side code, so it runs on the users' browser along side the parsed HTML code. There's no way for the client side JS to execute any PHP commands.

Comment: there are some nasty cases when PHP does output markup directly. Especially in legacy projects. Since refactoring might get much more expensive than patching... go figure.

Anyway, the snippet above makes little sense to me too, I tried to imagine the gaps and provide some agnostic ideas to it though. Anyway, seems like a "handle with care" situation, I wouldn't like to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could go this way:

```
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
var eventContent = $('<div class="event-info">' + '<h4 class="event-name">' + point.name + '</h4><hr>' +
        '<span><h5>Date: </h5>' +
        '<p class="event-date">' + point.edate + '</p></span>' +
        '<p class="event-description">'+ point.description +'</p>' + 
        '<input type="button" id="view-event"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="showDetails();" value="View Event" />'+
        '<a href="details.php?id=' + id + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove Event</a>' +
        '</div>');
```

---

Yet I find this a lot cleaner:

```
<div class="event-info">
  <h4 class="event-name"></h4>
  <hr>
  <span>
    <h5>Date: </h5>
    <p class="event-date"></p>
  </span>
  <p class="event-description"></p>
  <input type="button" id="view-event" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
    onclick="showDetails();" value="View Event" />
  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove Event</a>
</div>

// below is the javascript example for your manipulations

var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$('h4.event-name').html(point.name);
$('p.event-date').html(point.edate);
$('p.event-description').html(point.description);
$('p.event-description').html(point.description);
$('div.event-info a.btn').attr('href', 'details.php?id='+id);
```

With the latter, you can have a container for your event data (if, for example, you have to display more of them in the same page), then produce a list of ids from the database. The steps would be:

- have a div prepared (like an empty template)
- get the list of events (as an array, or better, JSON)
- pass the list from php to javascript into a JS variable (or maybe do an AJAX call)
- iterate through the array with JS

  - for each of them, clone the container and assign an unique id to it
  - for each container you'd have a slightly modified version of the JavaScript code (see below)

So you won't have to worry about readibility or reusability.

```
var id = point.id;
$('div#' + id + ' h4.event-name').html(point.name);
$('div#' + id + ' p.event-date').html(point.edate);
$('div#' + id + ' p.event-description').html(point.description);
$('div#' + id + ' p.event-description').html(point.description);
$('div#' + id + ' div.event-info a.btn').attr('href', 'details.php?id='+point.id);
```

As always, further improvements and suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: When calling id as a variable (var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;), it gives a Syntax Error "Unexpected token <"

Comment: you've got some atypical setup there, if you'd share more of it maybe someone can provide a better integrated answer. Anyway, this seems like a wrong approach on so many levels, you'd maybe want to consider a little refactoring.

Comment: I've tried another way by using javascript clone() - its been updated in the original question

Comment: as I said, I quote: *for each of them, clone the container and assign an unique id to it* :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is returning some event data. Have it return the event ID as well.

For instance if your page is returning JSON for the various events, include the ID in the JSON objects.